# Contact form 7 shortcode appear outside form tag

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have managed to do a test shortcode in my function.php and it does display on my contact 7 form. Oddly it display outside the form tag.

this is my shortcode

```
function cf7_shortcode()
{ ?>
<span>test shortcode</span>
<?php }

add_shortcode('cf7_shortcode', 'cf7_shortcode');
```

also i add another line to enable shortcode to be working inside contact form template

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'do_shortcode');
```

this is my form template

```
<label> Nama
[text* nama] </label>

<label> Emel
[email* emel] </label>

<label> No. Telefon
[tel* telefon] </label>

<label> Mesej
[textarea mesej] </label>
<br>
[cf7_shortcode]
[submit "Hantar"]
```

and this is what happen

[image: form code]

[image]

I have search on the internet how people do it and it exactly how i do it except my shorcode goes outside the form tag while other people are not. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your shortcode echoes the output than returning it — shortcodes should not echo the output, but `return` it — unless in certain cases like complex HTML markup in the output, where you need to use output buffering.

So your code should look like:

```php
function cf7_shortcode() {
    return '<span>test shortcode</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'cf7_shortcode', 'cf7_shortcode' );
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works now! so silly of me.